# Compute Cost of StreamingKMeans

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, cluster-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

My code use the class `StreamingKMeans` to clustering streaming data from kafka. I want calculate the error of model (WSSSE), but the class `StreamingKMeansModel` have this function `computeCost(RDD<Vector> data)`. The input is RDD and not DStream. I can't applicated this function to DStream. 
I solved the problem by doing this:

```
trainingData.saveAsTextFiles("/home/hduser/sbt_project/project1/Dstream/")
val rddTraining= ssc.sparkContext.textFile("/home/hduser/sbt_project/project1/Dstream/")
val vectorTraining=rddTraining.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
val WSSSE=model.latestModel().computeCost(vectorTraining)
```

But `saveAsTextFiles` create one folder each stream and `textFile`
 read from file not from a folder.

Can I resolve this issue? Can I append the stream to a file?

Comment: Why would you use streaming, when your data fits into memory cache? Why use a slower and lower quality approach than necessary? For clustering never use Spark, it's crap.

Comment: I use a streming data beacuse I received the data in streaming from Kafka.
Why is Spark crap for clustering? I have a lot of data and I wanted to model them with spark

Comment: Because the clustering functionality available in Spark is nothing but toy code. Utterly incomplete functionality, bad numerics, slow. You'll get much better results with other tools. Clustering is hard. You can't just dump big data in it and expect to get anything meaningful. That never works.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice

Comment: And Spark performance isn't all that great. Except if you compare to the old on-disk MapReduce, as writing to disk repeatedly is slower than not writing (surprise!). If in doubt, benchmark yourself.